# Add MenuItem List to Parent Menu Item

Tags: java, menuitem, vaadin7

I have a MenuItem List

```
MenuItem restart= schedules.addItem("Restart", null);
MenuItem start= schedules.addItem("start", null);
MenuItem stop= schedules.addItem("stop", null);
List<MenuItem> menuItems = new ArrayList<MenuItem>();
        menuItems.add(restart);
menuItems.add(start);
menuItems.add(stop);
```

Also I have a Parent MenuItem and the schdules is the MenuBar.

```
MenuItem options= schedules.addItem("Restart", null);
```

My Question is is there any way to add My `MenuItem` List(`menuItems`) to my Parent `MenuItem` (`options`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know if a understood correctly what you need to do but i will try. You can use a loop in your List menuItems and call setParent(MenuItem parent) on each object, setting the parent there.